# How to set custom icons for Lightning Scheduler Appointment Types

Tags: lightning-scheduler

When configuring `Lightning Scheduler`, it is possible to add custom `Appointment Types`.

When the user uses Lightning Schedulers built-in `Flow` it displays the custom `Appointment Type` as a lightning icon.

[image]

How can I change the lightning icons to something more relevant to the actual value?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to edit the API names for the entries in the Default Appointment Type Picklist Values on Work Type. The API name determines which utility icon is assigned to what appointment type. (API names can be different from their corresponding labels.) The list of supported utility icons is documented here: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/#utility.